# How can I toggle a VS Code extension on and off with a keyboard shortcut? (It has a built in on and off setting)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to toggle `vscode-eslint` on and off, but in the shortcut section if I select the same key then it says 'eslint is already enabled' on pressing it.

```
  {
    "key": "pausebreak",
    "command": "eslint.disable"
  },
  {
    "key": "pausebreak",
    "command": "eslint.enable"
  }
```

I can't find a `When` to say when it is enabled disable and disabled enable.

Comment: There are a couple of extensions mentioned here https://medium.com/hack-visual-studio-code/toggle-any-setting-in-vs-code-using-keyboard-shortcut-arguments-cdb5ddc56955 to toggle settings that may help.

Comment: @Mark thanks for the link! I was hoping no more extensions as it seems so basic, oh well.